# How to prevent primefaces ajax calls from disabling my scripts

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

My Js Code has set an `onclick` on a component class inside a `selectOneMenu`, whenever I use `<p:ajax>` inside my selectOneMenu, the script runs only once.
how to prevent that?

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="GaStructNode_listForm_GaStruct"
        value="#{gaStructNodeController.selectedGaStruct}"
        style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.defautlItem}"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{gaStructNodeController.findAllGaStructs()}" var="gs"
        itemLabel="#{gs.name}" itemValue="#{gs}"/>
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="@form :GaStructNode_listForm :GaStructNode_editForm :GaStructNode_picklist_form"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.ui-selectonemenu-item-group').click(function () {
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your script inside a function and call it form the oncomplete of the `p:ajax`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.ui-selectonemenu-item-group').click(function () {
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");
    });

    function m() {
        $('.ui-selectonemenu-item-group').click(function () {
            alert("Handler for .click() called.");
        });
    }
</script>
```

and change your ajax:

```
<p:ajax oncomplete="m()" event="itemSelect" update="@form :GaStructNode_listForm :GaStructNode_editForm :GaStructNode_picklist_form"/>
```